# Multiple-item bounded Knapsack algorithm

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a list of items that each have a price - or in terms of the Knapsack problem, a weight. The number of purchasable items are only limited by a budget, so it is possible to buy as many of each as desirable, as long as the total amount spent isn't over a certain constant. I also have an algorithm that, based on certain variables, tells how profitable each item is (i.e. the value of each item). So basically I have a bounded Knapsack problem with the extra condition that more than one of each item fits into the knapsack.

I want to maximize the profit under these conditions. I understand that there isn't an efficient solution, but is there at least a feasible one?

Comment: Is a solution that has the same complexity as a standard knapsack feasible?

Comment: a dp array of size budget will be needed, complexity will be O(budget*(size of item list))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let **dp[i]** be the maximum profit that can be earned if our budget is **i**. And **cost[j]** denote cost of **j** item and **p[j]** the profit earned from it. I assume **cost[]** and **profit[]** are given. Then following is the code in c++. ( let there be **n** items ).

```
  int max_profit(int budget )
  {
       if(budget<=0)
         return 0;
       if(dp[budget]!=-1)return dp[budget];
       int ans=0;
       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       {
             if(cost[i]<=budget)
               ans=max(ans,profit[i]+max_profit(budget-cost[i]));
       }
       dp[budget]=ans;
       return ans;
  }
  memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
  cout<< max_profit(budget);
```

Time Complexity is **O(budget*(size of item list ))**,Memory **O(budget)**. Also I assumed everything 
fits in int.

Comment: I think it should be `cost[i] <= budget`, not `cost[i] >= budget`.

Comment: Should still check `budget <= 0` instead of `budget == 0` even though internally to the function you only call if `cost[i] <= budget` because the first call may come in with a negative value, which could cause a segfault.

Comment: @AndyG initial budget being negative does not make sense and apart from that budget will never be -ve, but still included it thanks

Comment: @migdal: Agreed about the nonsensical part. If there's one thing I've learned though, it's to protect the user against themselves, even if I'm the user.

Comment: yeah i agree to the part that code should handle such things (y)